# ¿Cómo puedo codificar la letra Ñ en php?

Tags: php, array

Tengo una función de descifrado César con el abecedario como un array, que recibe como parámetro de entrada la frase de la otra función, pero al momento de descifrar la letra Ñ no es decodificada, si no que es "omitida". Cual podría ser la solución?

```php
function ccifrado()
{
    $textocifrado = " ";
    $abc = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    $d=rand(1,27);
    $ar_d=array();

    for ($i=$d; $i <count($abc) ; $i++) { 
        array_push($ar_d, $abc[$i]);
    }
    for ($i=0; $i <$d ; $i++) { 
        array_push($ar_d, $abc[$i]);

    }
    $textoingresado = (readline("Ingrese la palabra a cifrar: "));
    $ar_f = str_split((strtoupper($textoingresado))); 
    foreach ($ar_f as $p => $l) {
        foreach ($abc as $pp => $lp) {
            if ($l == $lp) {
                //echo $ar_d[$pp].' ';
            
                $textocifrado .= $ar_d[$pp];
            }
        }
    }
    /*var_dump($abc);
    echo $d;
    var_dump($ar_d);*/
    echo("------------------------------\n");
    echo "Frase cifrada: ". $textocifrado."\n";
    echo "Clave generada: ".$d;
}
```

**EDITADO: Me confundí de función**.
Estoy añadiendo al post como me devuelve a mi cuando quiero cifrar la palabra mañana como ejemplo del caso.

```
function descifrado($d, $textocifrado)
{
    $abc = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    $ar_d=array();
    $textodescifrado="";

    for ($i=$d; $i <count($abc) ; $i++) { 
        array_push($ar_d, $abc[$i]);
    }
    for ($i=0; $i <$d ; $i++) { 
        array_push($ar_d, $abc[$i]);

    }
    $ar_f=str_split(strtoupper($textocifrado));
    foreach ($ar_f as $p => $l) {
        foreach ($ar_d as $pp => $lp) {
            if ($l == $lp) {
                //echo $abc[$pp].' ';
                //sleep(1);
                $textodescifrado .= $abc[$pp];
            }
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo "Frase descifrada: ". $textodescifrado."\n";
    echo "Clave usada: ".$d."\n";
}
```

[image: screenshot de la consola]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo para reproducir el problema? [Probé tu código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/recPK.png) y no veo ningún problema.

Comment: Justamente todas las letras Ñ no las cifra, las devuelve igual. después en la función de descifrado las letras Ñ desaparecen.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿cual es la función de descifrado? Al parecer tu pregunta esta incompleta. Por favor, presiona [edit] y agrega todo lo necesario para reproducir el error.

Comment: Gracias amigo, ahí edité la pregunta.

Comment: No-respuesta: Como sugerencia, para preservar la salud mental propia y ajena, elige nombres de variable que digan qué hace. `dd`, `pp`, `d` no dicen absolutamente nada ;) Échale un ojo a CleanCode. Lo otro: el texto cifrado tiene CINCO caracteres (debería ser `IWKWJW`), así que ya viene incompleto. Te tocó añadir la función de cifrado a tu pregunta :P

Comment: Justamente por eso decía, que las letras Ñ no las puede leer, por eso falta una letra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si prestas atención en el manual

- [`strtoupper`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtoupper):

> Notar que ser 'alfabético' está determinado por la configuración regional actual. Por ejemplo, en la configuración regional por defecto "C" caracteres como la diéresis-a (ä) no se convertirán.

- [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split):

> str_split() realizará la división en bytes en lugar de en caracteres cuando trata con un string codificado en multibyte.

Por tal motivo es necesario recurrir al uso de las funciones provistas por [`mbstring`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.mbstring.php):

> mbstring proporciona funciones específicas para cadenas de texto multibyte que ayudan a tratar codificaciones multibyte en PHP. Además, mbstring controla la conversión de la codificación de caracteres entre los posibles esquemas de codificación. mbstring está diseñada para manejar codificaciones basadas en Unicode, tales como UTF-8 y UCS-2

#### Solución:

- Reemplazar `strtoupper` por [`mb_strtoupper`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtoupper)
- Reemplazar `str_split` por [`mb_str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-str-split)

Tanto en la función encriptadora como en la desencriptadora.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Marcos por la paciencia jaja, me solucionó el problema, el único inconveniente es que no tenía instalada la función esa. Pero ahora que está instalada si me funciona!